# kubectl exec less command and the output cannot be redirected

Tags: linux, kubernetes, alias

I defined some commands in `/etc/profile`:

```
alias umcd="kubectl exec -ti -n actiontech-dmp \
$(k get pods| awk '/'umc'/{print$1}')  \
-c umc -- less /var/log/actiontech/umc/detail.log"
```

This single alias command works fine, I can see the detail log. However, whenever I run this command:

```
umcd | grep "some key word" or
```

```
umcd > detail.log.
```

**The command line tool just hangs up forever...**

What is happening? I don't have a single clue about it and it's sad that google doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you are using `less` command which is *file viewer* - [it is user interface tool, it is changing terminal behaviour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217036/redirect-output-of-less-utility-to-a-file/217044#217044), while `cat` just reads data [from file and outputs it to the terminal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cat-command-in-linux-with-examples/).

`less` command is too much complex tool for your use and it is not recommended to use it for simple redirection or for matching patterns using `grep` because it may cause issues like that.

In your case, `cat` command is right tool. Just change your alias to:

```
alias umcd="kubectl exec -ti -n actiontech-dmp \
$(k get pods| awk '/'umc'/{print$1}')  \
-c umc -- cat /var/log/actiontech/umc/detail.log"
```

It will work properly.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you Mikolaj! It works perfectly!

Comment: any idea how i can modify this for a kubectl command running from a bash script which goes as: 

```kubectl exec <pod_name> -it -- /bin/bash -c "<postgresql query>" > output.txt```

what i'm trying to do is run query on another postgres pod and save result in current pod in file output.txt